# Java Try With Resources - Order of Closing Resources

Tags: java, try-with-resources

On running the below code

```
class MyResource1 implements AutoCloseable {
    public void close() throws IOException {
        System.out.print("1 ");
    }
}

class MyResource2 implements Closeable {
    public void close() throws IOException {
        throw new IOException();
    }
}

public class MapAndFlatMap {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try (
                MyResource1 r1 = new MyResource1();
                MyResource2 r2 = new MyResource2();
            ) {
            System.out.print("T ");
        } catch (IOException ioe) {
            System.out.print("IOE ");
        } finally {
            System.out.print("F ");
        }
    }
}
```

I am getting the below output

```
T IOE 1 F
```

But I was expecting

```
T 1 IOE F
```

Even after changing the order of resources in try like the following

```
MyResource2 r2 = new MyResource2();
    MyResource1 r1 = new MyResource1();
```

There is no change in output .In my understanding the resources will be closed in opposite direction of their declaration . Is it correct ?

Comment: If you wanted to test order of closing, why not print something in MyResource2 close method instead of exception? You are now testing order of closing resources vs handling exceptions

Comment: Or put a breakpoint and use a debugger

Comment: @AsthaSrivastava Yes it is..

Comment: I see `T 1 IOE F` as you say you're expecting.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is a documented behavior: "[close methods of resources are called in the opposite order of their creation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html)"